# Date Picker material UI - open on specific date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am using Material-UI's DatePicker component to select some dates.

My app requires 2 dates to be selected (figure 1), and the second date can not be previous to the first one. Thus, I disable the past dates using the "minDate" prop. However, if the first date selected is, for example, a month from now, this still opens the datepicker on the current date, instead of the minimum allowed date.

Example: I select 15 August as the first date (figure 2), and when I click the second date, it opens on the current date (figure 3)

Instead of this, **I would like for the datepicker to be opened on the minimum allowed date.**

Any suggestions on how to do this?

DatePicker code:

```html
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import moment from 'moment'

const DateSelect = (props) => {
  const { minDate, onSetDate, index } = props
  return(
    <DatePicker 
      textFieldStyle = {{width: 100}}
      onChange = {(dc, date) => onSetDate(date, index)}
      hintText = {index === 0 ? "Earliest" : "Latest"}
      minDate = {minDate}
      container = "inline"
      formatDate = {(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
    />
  )
}

DateSelect.defaultProps = {
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSetDate: () => {},
  index: 0,
}

export default DateSelect
```

[image: Figure 1 - select two dates - second date can not be previous to the first]

[image]

[image]